# HCl/H2O with alkene: Which one reacts?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

[image]

I think that the initial step forms a tertiary amine, which then in the presence of the ketone and trace acid undergoes nucleophilic addition. But then, for the $\ce{HCl/H2O}$ in the last step, which one reacts with the double bond in **1G**?

Comment: Do you intend to ask whether HCl adds to the pi bond or water adds to the pi bond?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yes, my point exactly. I'm not sure if it's a trick question or my misinterpretation.

Comment: @Carlson Miller: See my amendment to Das's solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the **last step  is for the Hydrolysis**. 
 After reaction with $\ce{LiAlH_4}$, the amide is reduced to amine and thus when it is reacted with a ketone it forms an **imine**($1G$) like this below,
[image]

which quickly **tautomerises** to form the most stable **Enamine** as this 
[image]

After  that when it is reacted with $\ce{CH_3Br}$, the nitrogen's lone pair conjugates and the nucleophilic attack occurs from the adjacent carbon(like Michael addition) with attached methyl group. Thus you have the intermidiate substituted proiduct as, 
[image]

But this imine  is hydrolysed in the presence of $\ce{H^+/H_2O}$ to give you back the original **ketone** but with an extra methyl group attached to it. So I think your final product $1H$ should be this, 
[image]

and also you get the amine after hydrolysis which is actually the  same as $1F$.

Comment: (+1) Good answer. Though your lines looks a bit crooked. I would recommend using [Marvinsketch](https://marvinjs-demo.chemaxon.com/latest/) it's online and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

The product in @Soumik Das's otherwise fine solution should be 2,6-dimethylcyclohexanone (**4**) NOT the 2,2-isomer **7**. The enamines (pyrrolidine, piperidine, morpholine) of 2-methylcyclohexanone **6** are more stable as structure **1** rather than structure **2**. The methyl group in enamine **1** is undoubtedly axial to avoid the A<sup>1,3</sup> interaction present in enamine **2**. The kinetic alkylation product, imine **3**, probably has trans methyl groups but acid hydrolysis will likely equilibrate the trans and cis ketones to the more stable cis isomer **4**. This very reaction with a different secondary amine is discussed in [Gilbert Stork's 1963 paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00885a021).
 
[image]

G. Stork, et al., *J. Am. Chem. Soc*., **1963**, *85*, 207.
DOI: 10.1021/ja00885a021